# Secured Spring boot API JS fetch() returns login page html

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, fetch

The Spring boot application has some REST APIs which are protected by authentication. If I login and acces the APIs from browser, it works fine. But if I call the APIs from a JavaScript fetch() call from different origin, it returns the login page rather than the requested data. Generally, this happens if I access any authentication protected page when while not being loged in. So I guess the JS fetch() function is not sending the cookies.

But adding `credentials: 'include'` in the headers does not solve the problem.

My web security config -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.cors()
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin", "/api/**", "/admin/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                        .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured during handling security: " + e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = 
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                    .username("user")
                    .password("pass")
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();
        
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://127.0.0.1:8090"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

And my fetch() command -

```
fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include'
       }).then(response => {
        response.text().then(data => {
            console.log(data);
...
```

Is my guess right?

How do I solve this?

Comment: It's not the fetch issue for sending the cookies, I think your browser session doesn't includes the cookies. When you login, making a POST request, it should also specific credentials to be included. Can you request for authentication using the `REST` route rather than login & then hitting the `GET` route?

Comment: @AshishYadav If I am understanding your comment right, yes I can do that. Being logged out, I can hit the API and it would redirect me to login. After successful login, it returns with the requested information in the browser in JSON format as expected. But through JS fetch(), it does not work this way.